Should I merge GND and COM?
I'm building an dual supply op-amp circuit. I'm using a Isolated DC-DC converter module to supply op-amp with +-15V. The module ouput is labeled 'COM' and isolated from the input GND. The input signal to op-amp references GND but op-amp supply references COM. What should op-amp feedback and output reference? Should I just connect two grounds together.


Your actual need for a isolated DC-DC is up for debate.  However, you may want to take another look at that supply.  It's relatively noisy, and its minimum output current requirements for regulation is a hefty 80mA.  You will likely be disappointed with the results.

@ChrisKnudsen We're using this module because it's what we have at our lab. İf I don't need isolation then should I connect COM and GND?

If you don't connect them you will, in effect, add the difference between them to your input signal.

... which will likely lead to terrible noise and the signal being out of the allowable common-mode input voltage range.

I thought isolated power supplies are considered better and less noisy. Is there way to reduce ripple noise like using bulk capacitances?

"I thought isolated power supplies are considered better and less noisy." In this field there is no any-one-thing that is always better than any-other-one thing without considering the project requirements and environment.  One uses an isolated supply (with its likely additional considerations and requirements) when one needs an isolated supply.  Isolated does not guarantee 'better' for any specification.  Read and digest the datasheet line by line, and compare to other options.

@ChrisKnudsen Thank you.

Why is your OPAMP input referenced to GND instead of COM/GNDREF?

@brhans Because the input signal comes from a DAQ that's connected to PC with USB.

That doesn't really answer the question. Why can't "J2 IN" be connected to GNDREF instead of GND in this circuit?

That would mean connecting two grounds together which was my original question.

It would connect the ground of your signal source to the signal ground of your opamp - which is not necessarily the same thing as connecting the input ground of your 'isolated' power supply to your signal ground. You could be using an input supply completely independent of your signal source, like a small 'wall wart' or something like that.

You must connect GND and COM or it won't work.
As an example, if you have an op-amp with +15V and -15V supplies referenced to GND, the inputs and outputs must be well within +15V and -15V.
If you simply have an arbitrary 30V floating supply compared to input/output signal reference, like floating at 100V, the op-amp supplies floating at 100V and 130V are useless as the signal and signal ground are way beyond limits of working properly or causinh damage.
